# Javascript alter display based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashtag

I have 4 div's on the page with unique ID's. Example external link:
`www.website.com/page.html#one`.

I need the display (set to none) to change to block. I'm at a bit of a loss (my JavaScript isn't very strong). Any ideas? Below is the code I'm using to parce the url, and the div id's are literally just `one`, `two`, `three`, and `four`.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var hashVal = window.location.hash.split("#")[1];

    $("#" + hashVal).style.display = 'block';

});
```

Comment: window.location.hash.slice(1) works just as well for getting the hash value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need to split the hash tag by the hash mark if you're going to use it as a selector. (see [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location))

And, for jQuery, you're looking for the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method i believe:

```
$(window.location.hash).css('display','block');
```